# How RXJS type inference work when multiple pipe is used typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, intellisense

```js
const of = require('rxjs').of;
const map = require('rxjs/operators').map

of(123).pipe(
  map(num => num.toString()),
  map(str => str.substring(0,1)),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

In the second `map` above, the type of `str` parameter is correctly inferred from the previous `map` that returns a `string`. I am curious how typescript is inferring the type in the second map operator.

Is this RxJS who nicely designed the code so that it can happen?
Or is it just VS code that has special IntelliSense for RxJS?

Comment: A bit unclear what the question is. rxjs, has typescript definition files. You can examine the ts definitions of `pipe` and  `map` (use go to definition) and see how they use generics to forward the types. If you have specific questions around those, those can be answered, but this seems to vague to me.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: my assumption was that `pipe` is a method that takes variable length arguments, which is not. This is why I got confused about how the type is being inferred in the second operator. It was clear from this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205100/887149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it is all handled by RxJS.

Looking at the [`pipe` overloads](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L309-L319)

```js
pipe(): Observable<T>;
  pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
  pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
  pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
...
```

we can see that there's a lot going on.

`OperatorFunction<T, A>` type refers to a function whose single parameter is an **Observable** of type `T` and whose **return type** is also an Observable of type `A`:

```js
export interface OperatorFunction<T, R> extends UnaryFunction<Observable<T>, Observable<R>> {}
```

Let's also have a look at [`map`'s signature](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L44)

```js
export function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R> { ... }
```

As you can see, its return type will be a function that receives an observable and returns another observable. In this case, the **type** of the **returned Observable**(`R`) is **inferred** from the provided projection function: `(value: T, index: number) => R`

So, if you have

```js
const src$ = of(1).pipe(map(v => '' + v));
```

`src$` will be an observable whose type `T` will be `string`.

And here's why type inference also works inside [`subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L74):

```js
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription; // Providing callbacks

subscribe(observer?: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription; // Providing an observer object
```

where `T` is the inferred type of the Observable(i.e from `map`'s provided fn in this case).

Comment: I just assumed that `pipe` is just one function taking varargs. But now I looked into the code and looks like they have given a total of 10 fixed-sized methods plus one method with varargs.